# Is it possible to develop Unity Apps for Oculus Go on Windows 7?

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, adb, oculusgo

The [link](https://medium.com/inborn-experience/how-to-build-an-app-for-the-oculus-go-from-start-to-finish-with-unity-cb72d931ddae) provides a thorough walkthrough on how to get up and running doing this, however on Windows 7 step 8.3 can't be completed (Install adb driver for Oculus Go). I receive the message, "The INF file you selected does not support this method of installation". I've read elsewhere the cited driver is targeting Windows 10.

On the GearVR we need ADB to generate a serial which is in turn used to generate an OSIG file. ADB does list the Galaxy s7 as a device. However, the OSIG file is not required for the Oculus Go though apparently, but ADB is required to transfer the app from Unity to the Go.

The issue is i cant install the adb driver for Oculus Go cited in section 8, meaning the device is not listed in adb devices.

Does this mean i must use Windows 10 to deploy an app to the Oculus Go or is there a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you install it on Windows 7?  Also, did you make sure to install the Galaxy s7 Drivers on your machine?  Sometimes then dont appear in ADB because you haven't installed the driver.  (This was my issue when I tried)

Comment: @Eddge - thanks for commenting - the S7 is already listed in ADB devices i did this just to check adb was working for a phone i had setup previously. The issue is i cant install the adb driver for oculus Go because when i try i get "The INF file you selected does not support this method of installation".

Comment: my bad I misread I for some reason thought you said the s7 wasnt listed... I will look around and see if I can find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I went through this myself recently as one of my laptops was running Windows 7.
I did eventually upgrade but I wanted to share my solution.

### Solution that worked for me on Windows 7 (64 Bit)

1. Open Device Manager (Click Start, Control Panel, Device Manager)
2. Locate the device (yellow exclamation mark)
3. Right-click and select **Update Driver Software**
4. Select **Browse my computer for driver software**
5. Select **Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer**
6. Choose **Non-Plug and Play Drivers**
7. Choose **Have Disk**
8. Navigate to your **android_winusb.inf** file and install it.

Some note that you may (temporarily or not) need to disable development mode on your Oculus Go for the device to detect correctly.

### How to disable development mode for Oculus Go if needed

1. Open the Oculus app on your mobile device.
2. In the Settings menu, select your Oculus Go headset that you're using for development.
3. Select More Settings.
4. Toggle Developer Mode off.